# "It" statement keep using regular database instead of the test database

Tags: node.js, mongoose, jestjs, nestjs, supertest

I am  doing some testing and I just want to test my endpoint. What goes in and what does out that's it.

I have a test database that I want to use when the test run.

in "BeforeAll" I connect to the test database and in my beforeach I make a post of a user.
It work it's inserted in the test database

The problem is as soon as I try to make a request in a "It" statement , the database used is app one not the test database :/

```
beforeAll(async () => {
    await mongoose.connect(testDatabase);
});
afterAll(async function () {
    await mongoose.disconnect()
});

describe('/user', () => {
    let app;

    beforeEach(async () => {
        const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
            imports: [AppModule, UserModule],
        }).compile();

        app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();
        await app.init();

        // this send correctly data to the TEST database
enter code here
        return request(app.getHttpServer()) 
            .post('/user').send(TEST_USER)
            .set('Accept', 'application/json')
            .expect(201)
            .then(r => console.log("Result of post", r.body))
    });

    it('GET', () => {
        // my probleme here : this retrieve the regular database content (setup in main file) NOT THE TEST database setup in beforeAll
        return request(app)
            .get('/user')
            .expect(200)
            .then(r => console.log("Result of get", r.body))
    });
});
```

I am doing it wrong ?
Thank you guys !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally my mistake was in this line :

imports: [AppModule, UserModule],

App module override my test's mongoose. connect with another connection established inside.

Answer (score 0):

My bet is that your app is not using the connection you establish there - you app, during the request, most likely creates its own connection.
Could you show minimum reproduction repository with the mvp implementation of your route under test, including the module and dependencies?